# Minimum To Maximum in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a question about a piece of code I am writing.

```
Set /a 4DgtNum= %Random% %%9999
```

That's what is being used. I need to know how could I make a "Start at this number end in the range of another" code like start at (I.E 1000 and the max you can go to is 9999, but use any number between that ratio).

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

```batch-file
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

For %%b IN (#) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,30000) DO CALL :choosernd&SET /a #!num!+=1
SET #
GOTO :eof

:choosernd
set /a min=1000
set /a max=9999

set /a min=1
set /a max=5

set /a rangesize=max-min+1

SET /a numranges=32767/rangesize
SET /a maxrange=rangesize * numranges-1

:chooseagain
set /a num=%RANDOM%
if %num% gtr %maxrange% GOTO chooseagain
SET /a num=(num %% rangesize) + min
rem ECHO %num%

GOTO :EOF
```

This question has been asked many times on SO. Here's a generate-and-test routine.

The meat of the matter is the `:choosernd` routine, where you set your minimum and maximum values.

I overrode your `1000` and `9999` with `1` and `5` for ease of testing.

First, calculate range size. That part should be obvious.

Next - the random-number generator returns `%random%` in the range 0..32767, so using `%random% %% 100` for instance would return 328 numbers in 0..67, but 327 in 68..99. Hence, calculate the number of full ranges (327) available, and the maximum value to obtain an even distribution; (100*327)-1=32699.

Get a random number, but reject any that are greater than the maximum, so reject 32700..32767.

Perform a modulus operation on the chosen, filtered number and add the minimum, giving `num`

The code before this is simply clearing any variables whose names begin `#` and then executing the `:choosernd` routine 30,000 times. Each time, the variable #!num! is incremented, where `delayedexpansion` (which is explained many. many times on SO - use the `search` facility) is used to correctly choose a counter.

Then the counter is displayed for verification (the "random" generator is not particularly good)

Note that `delayedexpansion` is used only in the logging routine - it does not need to be invoked for the `:choosernd` routine.

Also - note that variablenames may not start with a digit.

When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.